# Attachement Meta DATA

Tags: attachments

we try to connect our Managment Software to Wordpress / Woocommerce.

Our customers can edit and manage product, stock and category directly from our sofware.

Wordpress Database is simply so we easly reach our goal.

The only problem left is the "Image Management".

Our main problem si the wp_attachment_metadata:

```
a:5:{s:5:"width";i:910;s:6:"height";i:607;s:4:"file";s:10:"t-logo.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:15:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:18:"t-logo-300x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:18:"t-logo-600x600.jpg";s:5:"width";i:600;s:6:"height";i:600;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:12:"medium_large";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:18:"t-logo-768x512.jpg";s:5:"width";i:768;s:6:"height";i:512;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:5:"large";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:18:"t-logo-910x448.jpg";s:5:"width";i:910;s:6:"height";i:448;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:19:"yith_wcbr_logo_size";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:16:"t-logo-45x30.jpg";s:5:"width";i:45;s:6:"height";i:30;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:24:"yith_wcbr_grid_logo_size";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:16:"t-logo-90x60.jpg";s:5:"width";i:90;s:6:"height";i:60;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:17:"raworganic-medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:18:"t-logo-680x380.jpg";s:5:"width";i:680;s:6:"height";i:380;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:15:"raworganic-blog";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:18:"t-logo-680x453.jpg";s:5:"width";i:680;s:6:"height";i:453;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:21:"woocommerce_thumbnail";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:18:"t-logo-300x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:9:"uncropped";b:1;}s:18:"woocommerce_single";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:18:"t-logo-600x400.jpg";s:5:"width";i:600;s:6:"height";i:400;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:29:"woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:18:"t-logo-250x361.jpg";s:5:"width";i:250;s:6:"height";i:361;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:12:"shop_catalog";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:18:"t-logo-300x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:11:"shop_single";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:18:"t-logo-600x400.jpg";s:5:"width";i:600;s:6:"height";i:400;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"shop_thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:18:"t-logo-250x361.jpg";s:5:"width";i:250;s:6:"height";i:361;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"shop_magnifier";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:18:"t-logo-600x600.jpg";s:5:"width";i:600;s:6:"height";i:600;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}
```

we are unable to generate this data for the image, because we can't understand these value:

***a:5....s:12....s:9***

This meta change every images.

You know what this fields stand for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is the attachment's data in serialized format. There's an explanation of the data in the [`wp_get_attachment_metadata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) codex entry.

If you have some custom function doing image uploading, you can use [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata) to generate that data.

Answer (score 0):

wp_attachment_metadata contains serialized array. You have to unserialize data to JSON format (for example) and you will know everything ;)

Here is your code in PHP array format:

```
array (
  'width' => 910,
  'height' => 607,
  'file' => 't-logo.jpg',
  'sizes' => 
  array (
    'thumbnail' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-300x300.jpg',
      'width' => 300,
      'height' => 300,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
    'medium' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-600x600.jpg',
      'width' => 600,
      'height' => 600,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
    'medium_large' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-768x512.jpg',
      'width' => 768,
      'height' => 512,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
    'large' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-910x448.jpg',
      'width' => 910,
      'height' => 448,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
    'yith_wcbr_logo_size' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-45x30.jpg',
      'width' => 45,
      'height' => 30,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
    'yith_wcbr_grid_logo_size' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-90x60.jpg',
      'width' => 90,
      'height' => 60,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
    'raworganic-medium' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-680x380.jpg',
      'width' => 680,
      'height' => 380,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
    'raworganic-blog' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-680x453.jpg',
      'width' => 680,
      'height' => 453,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
    'woocommerce_thumbnail' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-300x300.jpg',
      'width' => 300,
      'height' => 300,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
      'uncropped' => true,
    ),
    'woocommerce_single' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-600x400.jpg',
      'width' => 600,
      'height' => 400,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
    'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-250x361.jpg',
      'width' => 250,
      'height' => 361,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
    'shop_catalog' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-300x300.jpg',
      'width' => 300,
      'height' => 300,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
    'shop_single' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-600x400.jpg',
      'width' => 600,
      'height' => 400,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
    'shop_thumbnail' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-250x361.jpg',
      'width' => 250,
      'height' => 361,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
    'shop_magnifier' => 
    array (
      'file' => 't-logo-600x600.jpg',
      'width' => 600,
      'height' => 600,
      'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ),
  ),
  'image_meta' => 
  array (
    'aperture' => '0',
    'credit' => '',
    'camera' => '',
    'caption' => '',
    'created_timestamp' => '0',
    'copyright' => '',
    'focal_length' => '0',
    'iso' => '0',
    'shutter_speed' => '0',
    'title' => '',
    'orientation' => '0',
    'keywords' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
);
```